# Derivative notation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

Are these valid and equivalent?

$${df \over d(x+y)} \iff f'(x+y) \iff \text{the derivative of } f \text{ with respect to x+y}$$

Or more generically:

$${d(func) \over d(args)} \iff func'(args) \iff \text{the derivative of the } func \text{ with respect to the } args$$

And how about any others?

Comment: It seems "fine" to me, you can define a variable $z=x+y$ and by substitution you get a valid expression.

Comment: @Masacroso If I were to use multiple arguments as in ${d(func) \over d(arg_1, arg_2)}$ would that still be valid or is this the reasoning behind partial derivatives?

Comment: I dont know @Elohgee, my knowledge in analysis and calculus is low, sry :(

Answer (score 1):

In books and lectures notes, you will see like this,   let $z=f(x,y)=x+y$ , since $x$ and $y$ aren't functions with respect to another variable, then 
\begin{equation}
dz=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy
=1dx+1dy.
\end{equation}

if we have  $z=f(x,y)=x(t)+y(t)$, since  $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are functions with respect to variable $t$, the derivative is given by Chain rule for functions of two indepentent variables, we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{dz}{dt}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}
.
\end{equation}

to find out more have a look at these links[click here](https://www.google.iq/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiZrubxs4TVAhXFuhoKHR_7D0UQFggzMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.utah.edu%2Fonline%2F2210%2Fnotes%2Fch16.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEBB0zc7T9OQTCHDm84dEeXCg3U7A) and here [for notations](https://www.google.iq/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwja0I73roTVAhWBnRoKHWK6Ak4QFghOMAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.maths.manchester.ac.uk%2F~cds%2Farticles%2Fderivative.pdf&usg=AFQjCNG87WRSGBZQCzbpIP7K8nXuXZlj5w) .